# best version for r15-s829 toshiba satellite

Tags: versions

i recently picked up a toshiba satellite r15-s829 at my local pawn shop and while i do love this little guy, im hoping that going back to ubuntu will make him better. i need to know which version of ubuntu is the best option and whether or not the tablet functions will work as i got this with the intent of being for my 3d modeling tasks and because i like the old school analog note taking features of the tablet pen function.

Answer (score 0):

From Googling the model number, the specs are:

- Intel Pentium® M Processor 735 1.70GHz, 2MB L2, 400MHz FSB
- 512MB DDR333 SDRAM

**You are definitely going to want Lubuntu.** For convenience, here's a direct link to Lubuntu 14.04 LTS: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.5/release/lubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: i actually have 2 GB RAM in JARVIS and he had 1 GB when i got him if that changes anything. probably should have mentioned that to begin with. the main concern i have is that the tablet functions will still work and if Sculptris has a linux port. the main deciding factor on if i do switch will be my ability to use Sculptris, SketchUp and TeamViewer

Comment: @JamesBryan - I hate to break it to you, but that computer is so old, **it's going to be completely useless for any 3D modeling.** That is a single-core CPU without hyper-threading. TBH, that computer isn't good for anything other than note taking. You won't even be ale to browse the internet at any reasonable speed with that.